# Zend - Custom attribute inside setMultiOptions

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I try to add custom attribute inside setMultiOptions but i can't.
I have something like:

```
$locale = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->getLocale();
$territories = Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('territory', $locale, 2);

$this->setMultiOptions($territories);
```

And this return:

```
<select class="field_container field_14 option_1 parent_1" data-field-id="14" style="" show="1" id="1_1_14" name="1_1_14">
    <option label="" value=""></option>
    <option label="Andorra" value="AD">Andorra</option> 
</select>
```

i want inside  to add custom attribute like

```
<option label="Andorra" **data-image="Graphics/Fruits/Andorra.png"** value="AD">Andorra</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add attributes in option tag, I use a specific helper instead of Zend_View_Helper_FormSelect.

This is my new helper  `My_View_Helper_FormSelectDy` in the `My\View\Helper\FormSelectDy.php` file

```
<?php

/**
 * Abstract class for extension
 */
require_once 'Zend/View/Helper/FormElement.php';


/**
 * Helper to generate "select" list of options
 *
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_View
 * @subpackage Helper
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */
class My_View_Helper_FormSelectDy extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement
{
    /**
     * Generates 'select' list of options.
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param string|array $name If a string, the element name.  If an
     * array, all other parameters are ignored, and the array elements
     * are extracted in place of added parameters.
     *
     * @param mixed $value The option value to mark as 'selected'; if an
     * array, will mark all values in the array as 'selected' (used for
     * multiple-select elements).
     *
     * @param array|string $attribs Attributes added to the 'select' tag.
     *
     * @param array $options An array of key-value pairs where the array
     * key is the radio value, and the array value is the radio text.
     *
     * @param string $listsep When disabled, use this list separator string
     * between list values.
     *
     * @return string The select tag and options XHTML.
     */
    public function formSelectDy($name, $value = null, $attribs = null,
        $options = null, $listsep = "<br />\n")
    {

        $info = $this->_getInfo($name, $value, $attribs, $options, $listsep);
        extract($info); // name, id, value, attribs, options, listsep, disable

        // force $value to array so we can compare multiple values to multiple
        // options; also ensure it's a string for comparison purposes.
        $value = array_map('strval', (array) $value);

        // check if element may have multiple values
        $multiple = '';

        if (substr($name, -2) == '[]') {
            // multiple implied by the name
            $multiple = ' multiple="multiple"';
        }

        if (isset($attribs['multiple'])) {
            // Attribute set
            if ($attribs['multiple']) {
                // True attribute; set multiple attribute
                $multiple = ' multiple="multiple"';

                // Make sure name indicates multiple values are allowed
                if (!empty($multiple) && (substr($name, -2) != '[]')) {
                    $name .= '[]';
                }
            } else {
                // False attribute; ensure attribute not set
                $multiple = '';
            }
            unset($attribs['multiple']);
        }

        // now start building the XHTML.
        $disabled = '';
        if (true === $disable) {
            $disabled = ' disabled="disabled"';
        }

        // Build the surrounding select element first.
        $xhtml = '<select'
                . ' name="' . $this->view->escape($name) . '"'
                . ' id="' . $this->view->escape($id) . '"'
                . $multiple
                . $disabled
                . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
                . ">\n    ";

        // build the list of options
        $list       = array();
        $translator = $this->getTranslator();
        foreach ((array) $options as $opt_value => $opt_label) {

            if (is_array($opt_label)
                    && (!isset($opt_label['attribut_spe']))
                    ) {
                $opt_disable = '';
                if (is_array($disable) && in_array($opt_value, $disable)) {
                    $opt_disable = ' disabled="disabled"';
                }
                if (null !== $translator) {
                    $opt_value = $translator->translate($opt_value);
                }
                $opt_id = ' id="' . $this->view->escape($id) . '-optgroup-'
                        . $this->view->escape($opt_value) . '"';
                $list[] = '<optgroup'
                        . $opt_disable
                        . $opt_id
                        . ' label="' . $this->view->escape($opt_value) .'">';
                foreach ($opt_label as $val => $lab) {
                    $list[] = $this->_build($val, $lab, $value, $disable);
                }
                $list[] = '</optgroup>';
            } else {
                if (isset($opt_label['attribut_spe']) 
                    && !(is_null($opt_label['attribut_spe']))
                    && (is_array($opt_label['attribut_spe']))
                        )
                $list[] = $this->_buildattribut($opt_label['attribut_spe'], $value, $disable);
                else
                $list[] = $this->_build($opt_value, $opt_label, $value, $disable);
            }
        }

        // add the options to the xhtml and close the select
        $xhtml .= implode("\n    ", $list) . "\n</select>";

        return $xhtml;
    }

    /**
     * Builds the actual <option> tag
     *
     * @param string $value Options Value
     * @param string $label Options Label
     * @param array  $selected The option value(s) to mark as 'selected'
     * @param array|bool $disable Whether the select is disabled, or individual options are
     * @return string Option Tag XHTML
     */
    protected function _build($value, $label, $selected, $disable)
    {
        if (is_bool($disable)) {
            $disable = array();
        }

        $opt = '<option'
             . ' value="' . $this->view->escape($value) . '"'
             . ' label="' . $this->view->escape($label) . '"';

        // selected?
        if (in_array((string) $value, $selected)) {
            $opt .= ' selected="selected"';
        }

        // disabled?
        if (in_array($value, $disable)) {
            $opt .= ' disabled="disabled"';
        }

        $opt .= '>' . $this->view->escape($label) . "</option>";

        return $opt;
    }
    /**
     * Builds the actual <option> tag
     *
     * @param array $attribut_spe Option's attributs
     *                          attribut_spe['affiche'] = 'xxx' => <option ...>'xxx'</option>
     *                          si attribut_spe['affiche'] n'existe pas =>  <option ...>attribut_spe["label"]</option>
     *                          si attribut_spe["not_escape_affiche"] = true alors <option ...>'xxx'</option>
     *                                                                       sinon <option ...>$this->view->escape('xxx')</option>
     *                          Toutes les autres valeurs de attribut_spe seront dans les attributs du tag 'option'
     *                          ex.: attribut_spe["class"] = 'toto' et attribut_spe["style"] = 'width:143px;'
     *                                      => <option class='toto' style='width:143px;'> ... </option>
     * @param array  $selected The option value(s) to mark as 'selected'
     * @param array|bool $disable Whether the select is disabled, or individual options are
     * @return string Option Tag XHTML
     */
    protected function _buildattribut($attribut_spe, $selected, $disable)
    {
        if (is_bool($disable)) {
            $disable = array();
        }

        $opt = '<option';
        foreach ($attribut_spe as $cle => $valeur){
            if ($cle == "affiche") continue;
            if ($cle == "not_escape_affiche") continue;
            $opt .= ' ' . $cle . '="' . $valeur . '"';
        }

        // selected?
        if (in_array($attribut_spe["value"], $selected)) {
            $opt .= ' selected="selected"';
        }

        // disabled?
        if (in_array($attribut_spe["value"], $disable)) {
            $opt .= ' disabled="disabled"';
        }

        $opt .= '>';

        if (isset($attribut_spe["affiche"]) && !empty($attribut_spe["affiche"]))
            $affiche = $attribut_spe["affiche"];
        else 
            $affiche = $attribut_spe["label"];

        if (isset($attribut_spe["not_escape_affiche"]) 
            && is_bool($attribut_spe["not_escape_affiche"])
            && $attribut_spe["not_escape_affiche"]){
            $opt .= $affiche;
        }
        else{
            $opt .= $this->view->escape($affiche);
        }

        $opt .= "</option>";

        return $opt;
    }
}
```

It's the same helper than `Zend_View_Helper_FormSelect`, and I add `_buildattribut()` method.

To use it, you can do this:

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_US');
$territories = Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('territory', $locale, 2);

$territories2 = [];
foreach($territories as $code => $territory){
    $territories2[] =  array('attribut_spe'=>
                                array('value'=> $code,
                                      'label'=> $territory,
                                      'data-image' => "Graphics/Fruits/$territory.png"
                                    )
                                );    
}

$territories_select = new  Zend_Form_Element_Select('territories');
$territories_select->setMultiOptions($territories2);

$territories_select->addDecorators(array(array('ViewHelper', array('helper' => 'formSelectDy'))));
```

If you have not your own library, don't forget to add `My` library helper in your `application.ini`

```
resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = "My/View/Helper"
```

Of course, adapt it to have the good value in your data-image attribute.

Hope it will help you